# Function to expand an array

Tags: excel, vba

How would I write a function that I can pass an array to and have it returned, but expanded by 1?

e.g.

```
myArray = expandArray(myArray)

Function expandArray(myArray As Long)
    Dim x As Integer
    x = UBound(myArray) + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
    expandArray = myArray

End Function
```

I'm getting a ByRef error with the above

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: I should have said, I'm getting a ByRef error

Comment: `myArray As Long` expects a Long, not an array

Comment: define myArray as variant

Comment: `myArray() As Long`

Comment: Note that while you can do this, it is not very efficient. For example, if you try to use this in a large loop to build up an array item by item, performance might visibly degrade. If you really want this sort of behavior, it might be better to use an [ArrayList](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/) (not part of VBA per se, but still easy to use from VBA). It is the difference between `O(n)` appending and (amortized) `O(1)` appending.

Comment: Look into `Collection` instead, which allows you do add items to an array,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force `myArray` to be an array and make it of type `Variant`. If you are sure your array only contains values of type `Long` then replace both `Variant` with `Long`.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myOriginalArray()
    myOriginalArray = Array(1, 2, 3)

    Dim MyReturnedArray()
    MyReturnedArray = expandArray(myOriginalArray)
   
    'because of ByRef both myOriginalArray and MyReturnedArray got expanded
End Sub

Function expandArray(ByRef myArray() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    x = UBound(myArray) + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
    expandArray = myArray
End Function
```

**But note that you can only give the array `ByRef` which means that the `myOriginalArray` will get expanded too!**

So it would be more clear to make it a procedure instead of a function

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myOriginalArray()
    myOriginalArray = Array(1, 2, 3)

    expandArray myOriginalArray 
    'the myOriginalArray got expanded because of ByRef
End Sub

Sub expandArray(ByRef myArray() As Variant)
    Dim x As Long
    x = UBound(myArray) + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
End Function
```

Or if you need the `myOriginalArray` to not to change,

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myOriginalArray()
    myOriginalArray = Array(1, 2, 3)

    Dim MyReturnedArray()
    MyReturnedArray = expandArray(myOriginalArray)

    'here only MyReturnedArray is the expanded version
End Sub

Public Function expandArray(ByRef myArray() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    x = UBound(myArray) + 1
    
    Dim ReturnArray() As Variant
    ReturnArray = myArray 'make sure only the return array gets expanded even with ByRef
    
    ReDim Preserve ReturnArray(x)
    expandArray = ReturnArray
End Function
```

---

#### Final thoughts

Note that if you use `ReDim Preserve` a lot, this comes with a high cost and slows down your code a lot. Sometimes it is more efficient to define a larger array that has empty slots than re-sizing an array multiple times.

Comment: The above assumes that `LBound(array)=0` which is not always the case.

Comment: A common practice is to **double** the capacity on each required resize event.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Good Points! The lower bound can be preserved if not `0`: `ReDim Preserve myArray(LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray) + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

First, see if a **[`Collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)** object would do the job

```
Public Sub TestCollection()

    Dim arr As New Collection
    
    arr.Add 100
    arr.Add 200
    arr.Add 300
    
    Debug.Print arr(1)
    ' 100
    
    Call arr.Remove(1)

    Debug.Print arr(1)
    ' 200
    
End Sub
```

But what **you cannot do** with a collection is to write to cells like

```
Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(arr.Count, 1).Value2 = arr
' Error
```

So if you need to expand an array then use the code below:

```
Public Sub TestExpandArray()
    Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2 As Variant
    
    arr1 = Array(100, 200, 300)
    arr2 = ExpandArray1(arr1, 2)
    ' result is 5 array
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
        Debug.Print i, arr2(i)
    Next i
    
    ' Now test a 2D array from a range. The size is 5×7 for example.
    arr1 = Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(5, 7).Value2
    
    arr2 = ExpandArray2(arr1, 1, 3)
    ' result is 6×10 array
    Debug.Print UBound(arr2, 1), UBound(arr2, 2)

End Sub

Public Function ExpandArray1(ByRef arr() As Variant, ByVal count As Long) As Variant()
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long
    i1 = LBound(arr, 1): i2 = UBound(arr, 1)
    i3 = i2 + count
    ReDim Preserve arr(i1 To i3)
    ExpandArray1 = arr
End Function

Public Function ExpandArray2(ByRef arr() As Variant, ByVal count1 As Long, ByVal count2 As Long) As Variant()
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long
    Dim j1 As Long, j2 As Long, j3 As Long
    i1 = LBound(arr, 1): i2 = UBound(arr, 1)
    j1 = LBound(arr, 2): j2 = UBound(arr, 2)
    i3 = i2 + count1: j3 = j2 + count2
    Dim res() As Variant
    ReDim res(i1 To i3, j1 To j3)
    For i3 = i1 To i2
        For j3 = j1 To j2
            res(i3, j3) = arr(i3, j3)
        Next j3
    Next i3
    ExpandArray2 = res
End Function
```

As you can see the code `ExpandArray1` to expand a 1D array can use the `Preserve` keyword and it straight forward. But, the code `ExpandArray2` to expand a 2D array cannot use `Preserve` and manual copying of data has to occur.